# How can I flush/empty my UART(RX) each time before I receive a new message?

Tags: c, uart, esp32

```
const int rxBytes = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_0, data, RX_BUF_SIZE, 10 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
```

Comment: Do you know when the messages are to arrive, or do they come at random times?

Comment: I receive the incoming mesage in "data", but I dont master the time of arrival. Which role does the time play?

Comment: You can poll the UART or configure it to interrupt the processor when a character / message is received.  If you know the frequency of messages, you can poll.  I would recommend interrupt processing.  Then, you can clear the UART whenever you get a character, and keep a buffer of received characters.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore input by flushing it?

Comment: I used  uart_"flush(UART_NUM_0);" but its not working.

Comment: @WeatherVane I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: The purpose of flushing an input buffer is to throw away its content. Why do you want to do that? How do you know a new message isn't already arriving? You have posted one line of code and it is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: const int rxBytes = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_0, data, RX_BUF_SIZE, 10 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
  if (rxBytes > 0) {
   data[rxBytes] = 0;
   for(size_t i = 0; i < rxBytes; i++){
    message[i] = data[i];
   }
   
  }
  free(data);
 return message;     //This the rest of the code

Comment: I have the same lack of understanding as @WeatherVane does.  Serial links are byte streams, and a 'flush' operation does not make much sense?  What would you be flushing?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how to paste the rest of the code. If not I would have done so. But I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To flush input data you can read from the uart repeatedly with a timeout of 0 until zero bytes are returned.